# Weird issues with frontend apollo and graphql

Tags: javascript, vue.js, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I'm using nuxt.js with apollo. So basically I have a button and when you press the button it makes a request to the graphql server. The first time I press the button it works perfectly. But the second time it returns the same data. Even though it never contacted the server the second time. I think it has something to do with apollo mistakenly caching data. But I don't know how to fix it. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

To disable cache you can do it globally or for a specific query.

Globally:

```js
new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link,
  defaultOptions: {
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
  }
})
```

For a specific query:

```js
apollo: {
  foo: {
    query: ...,
    fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
  }
}
```

Comment: I just tried it doesn't seem to solve the issue. It may not be a problem with caching

Answer (score 0):

It might also be apollo server  setting that is returning same data.
Please check if there is any caching enabled at server end.

cacheControl: { defaultMaxAge: 5 },

defaultMaxAge shoud be either set to 0 or cacheControl shoild not be there at all.

Comment: I've tried disabling caching on the frontend and backend. I'm not so sure it has to do with caching anymore.